# error which should be solved "then expected near"

Tags: lua

I have an error code in lua which I have tried long to fix. first: the code:

```
if boolean fs.isDirectory("C:/Program Files/Factorio/Config") == true then
end
else
    fs.makeDirectory("C:/Program Files/Factorio/Config")
end
```

When the game (factorio) boots up and fires up the code it igves this error:

```
data.lua:2:
recipe.lua:1: 'then' expected near 'fs'
```

I know that the first part (form data.lua:1: to recipe.lua:1:) means at what place the error exists. The code you say a couple lines up is that block.

Does anyone know what mistake I made, I am willing to give more background info when necessary.

**edit**

In an attempt to get the problem more isolated I changed the code to:

```
if boolean fs.isDirectory("C:/Program Files/Factorio/Config") == false then
    fs.makeDirectory("C:/Program Files/Factorio/Config")
end
```

This made no difference for the error but did isolate it to the first two lines intead of the first example.

---

#### solution

the site [thepowdertoy](http://powdertoy.co.uk/Wiki/W/Lua_API:File_System.html) had boolean before the fs parts. I never thought of taking it away, thanks to user @yuhao for noting it, the working code is:

```
if fs.isDirectory("C:/Program Files/Factorio/Config") == false then
    fs.makeDirectory("C:/Program Files/Factorio/Config")
end
```

Comment: I don't think you're supposed to put the `end` keyword before `else`

Comment: @abhishek I changed the code and the error persisted, cou you take another look?

Comment: @YuHao When looking for the isDirectory i came across this [site](http://powdertoy.co.uk/Wiki/W/Lua_API:File_System.html) from which i took the isDirectory parts of the code

I decided to take away the boolean part, and it worked. thanks a lot.